# Looking for a more obvious and more formal equivalent to a vulgar expression

Tags: terminology, slang

What is the non-slang form of "shitting on someone", like to throw someone down?

Comment: Macmillan dictionaries website has a thesaurus entry https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/shit-on

Answer (score 3):

To berate, insult, belittle, demean, lambaste, pillory, badmouth, etc.

Comment: I should note, that some of these relate to directly saying the things to the individual in question (the first four above) whereas others could be said to another person about the individual (the last three). Not sure which you mean, but likely the first type?